# Using VBA and REST to get Sharepoint document URL

Tags: excel, vba, rest, sharepoint

I manage inspection data for my company. We receive many inspection reports via a standardized excel template and I use a macro to gather all the relevant data from these reports. The data is compiled into a master sheet where each record is an inspection, and feeds into Power BI so the results can be shared to the rest of my team.

These reports are submitted via Sharepoint, and are then automatically downloaded to a local drive on my computer. My macro then scans the synced local receiving folder, processes any new inspections, and moves them to another local folder which syncs them to a secure, read-only Sharepoint folder. Below is a diagram to explain.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  SHAREPOINT
Excel Reports submitted online by                         Reports synced back
inspectors through Sharepoint                             up to online secure 
            |                                             read-only Sharepoint 
            |                                             folder
            |                                                      ^
            v                                                      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                   ON MY PC

Reports are synced to local -------> VBA macro      ------> Reports moved to
"receiving" folder on my PC          processes files        local "hosting"
                                                            file on my pc which 
                                                            syncs to Sharepoint
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is where it gets tricky:

I want to be able to add a link in my master excel file to the individual reports on Sharepoint (url not local address), so that someone on my team viewing the Power BI report can click to open the inspection report through excel online. I can't seem to figure out how to set up the REST API in my code to get the URL.

I've tried the code below but it returns nothing and I am sure it is way off:

```
URL = "http://lab/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Library()?$filter=FileLeafRef eq '" & oFile.Name & "'&$select=Title"

        Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        req.Open "GET", URL, False
        req.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
        req.SetCredentials "myEmail", "myPass", 0
        req.Send

        Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument.6.0")
        If Not objXML.LoadXML(req.ResponseText) Then
            Err.Raise objXML.parseError.ErrorCode, , objXML.parseError.reason
        End If

        mws.Range("AJ") = URL
```

Could anyone help point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time and assistance!

Comment: `URL` would be the URL you sent the HTTP GET request to (i.e. the REST API endpoint); if the document URI is in the XML payload you'll have to query that `objXML` object to retrieve it. But, since "it returns nothing", I take it that `Err.Raise` is where your procedure stops? If so, what's the error code & message? If not, are you getting any errors? If not, remove any `On Error Resume Next` that might be in the code you haven't posted, make sure `Option Explicit` is specified at the top (declare any missing variables).

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, I think you've helped get me going. I didn't realize you need to query the objXML. I'm going to investigate further.